Setting kernel parameters through snap
I wanted to try setting a kernel parameter as a workaround for a display problem.  It seems snap now handles this.  So I tried this:
$ sudo snap set system system.kernel.cmdline-append="initcall_blacklist=simpledrm_platform_driver_init"
error: cannot communicate with server: Get "http://localhost/v2/changes/109": dial unix /run/snapd.socket: connect: connection refused

So... has it set the parameter or not?  How do I even tell?  sudo snap get system system.kernel.cmdline-append has been sat there doing nothing for several minutes now...

Why do you think snap handles this? Are you using Ubuntu Core?

@muru it's what the documentation I found said.  It may have been the wrong documentation, but I thought that 24.04 used the same snap mechanism for this as Core?

No, there has been no such change in 24.04
